# Batch Class for Append

Tags: apex, batch

I have written the batch class for adding a count to my Custom field Project_ID__c. As my Project_ID__c contains the Data like 1,2,3 i.e
I want to append count in front of my Project_ID__c. For example ---

> Project_ID__c=1.1,
>                                                                       Project_ID__c=1.2,
>                                                                       Project_ID__c=1.3,
>                                                                       Project_ID__c=1.4,
>                                                                       Project_ID__c = 2.5

I want output like

```
Project_ID__c=1.1,
Project_ID__c=1.2,
Project_ID__c=1.3,
Project_ID__c=1.4,
```

Project_ID__c = 2.1

Here is my code

```
global class BatchClassDemo1 implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        string query = 'SELECT Task_ID__c,CreatedDate,Project_ID__c FROM NI_Project_Backlog_Tasks__c order By CreatedDate ';
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC , List<NI_Project_Backlog_Tasks__c> scope)
    {
        try
        {
            List<NI_Project_Backlog_Tasks__c> UpdateList = new List<NI_Project_Backlog_Tasks__c>();
            integer count = 1;
             for(NI_Project_Backlog_Tasks__c ni :scope)
             {
                 if(ni.Task_ID__c == null){
                     ni.Task_ID__c= ni.Project_ID__c + '.'+ String.valueOf(count);
                     count++; 
                      System.debug('ProjectID'+ni.Project_ID__c+'TaskID'+ni.Task_ID__c);
                 }

                 UpdateList.add(ni); 
             }
             update UpdateList; 
        }

        Catch(Exception e){

            system.debug('Exception due to --------------->'+e.getMessage()+'-------------->LineNo----------->'+e.getLineNumber());

        }
    }

     global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inizializating the count inside the execute, and it is a problem because you need to think that your batch will launch N number of execute.

**Example:**

Your query return 2000 records, and you had configurated a batch size of 200. The you will launch 1 start, 2000 / 200 executes, and 1 finish. The record 1 and 201 401.... will have the same count.

**Solution:**

To solve this problem, the batch needs to implement Database.Statefull and you need start the value of the counter in the star method. There is the documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm